# Как правильно организовать передачу события из отдельного потока в GUI на JavaFx?

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui, javafx

У меня есть *MainController* и класс *UDPServer*, который крутится в отдельном потоке и ждет сообщения, когда сообщение приходит, мне нужно отобразить его на GUI. Как правильно организовать такое взаимодействие?

```
public class UDPServer implements Runnable {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // ...

        if(message.equals("N1-M")){

            // пришло сообщение и нужно отобразить его в GUI
            // в моем случае отобразить значит изменить цвет vRectangle            
        }

        // ...
    }
}


public class MainController {

    // ...

    @FXML Rectangle vRectangle;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логика такова:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;


public class UDPServer implements Runnable {
    
        private MainController mc;
    
        public UDPServer(MainController mc){
            this.mc = mc;
        }
    
        // ...
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
    
            // ...
    
            if(message.equals("N1-M")){
                // пришло сообщение и нужно отобразить его в GUI
                // в моем случае отобразить значит изменить цвет vRectangle 

                 Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            mc.updateColor(Color.BLUE);   
                 });        
            }
    
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    
    public class MainController {
    
        // ...
    
        @FXML Rectangle vRectangle;
    
         public void updateColor(Color clr) {
               vRectangle.setColor(clr);
         }
        // ...
    }
```

При создании объекта UDPServer в классе MainController, нужно не забыть передать ссылку на объект класса контроллера.

Например:

```
@Override
public void initialize(.....) {
    new Thread(new UDPServer(this));
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Написал наглядный пример

Main.java

```
package example.update.color;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

ChildrenThread.java

```
package example.update.color;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class ChildrenThread implements Runnable {
    
    private final FXMLDocumentController fxmlCntllr;
    
    public ChildrenThread(FXMLDocumentController fxmlCntllr) {
        this.fxmlCntllr = fxmlCntllr;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fxmlCntllr.updateColor(new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1));
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="example.update.color.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="vRectangle" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="171.0" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="15.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
package example.update.color;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Rectangle vRectangle;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        new Thread(new ChildrenThread(this)).start();
    }    
    
    void updateColor(Color clr) {
        vRectangle.setFill(clr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но я так и не смог заставить код работать. Выбрасывается Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = pool-2-thread-1

Comment: @AlexeyChizhov, дополнил ответ... Код 100% рабочий. P.S. Перед этим еще успел наброcать вариант обмена данными между потоками без JavaFX http://goo.gl/mq1rbT

Comment: Спасибо еще раз большое. Я создал новый проект, полностью скопировал весь код, но при запуске у меня все равно Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `new Thread(new ChildrenThread(this)).start();` написать `Platform.runLater(new ChildrenThread(this));`

Comment: Очень странно, но на домашнем компе, проект, который не работал на работе отлично работает, без каких либо изменений. Вроде все одинаковое стоит, везде последние версии и все такое. Странно. Platform.runLater заработал если сделать так:       Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fxmlCntllr.updateColor(new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1));
                    }
                });

Answer (score -4):

Точного ответа не знаю - как идея:

1. Создать переменную глобальную типа `volatile` (atomic говорят помоднее)
2. Написать слушатель - при изменении значения переменной что-то
   сделать ...